# How quickly can a mob go back through a nether portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I push a cow through a portal, it can't travel back for a little while. How long is this delay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The minimum delay is 30 seconds.** (+the time it takes to teleport). However, if the entity never exited the portal after teleporting, it can't teleport back.